# Inactive the other forms until previous form detail is filled

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft3TT.png)In PHPMyadmin I have 4 tables which consitutes information of 4 forms.
Those are in order 1,2,3,4.

I am stuck on how to disable 2,3,4 until 1st form is filled.
After that enable them one by one as they order goes on.

I am looking on the web but can't figure out.
I am using php for this.
Any online example or anyone who has encountered this please leave some resources.

It is a Single Page Application.
I want to allow candidate details filling only when candidate information is filled in php.
Please check the below images.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W67lS.png)

Comment: Are these forms on same page? How you are handling form submission? Please share more information.

Comment: Far too many unknowns here and far too broad a question. Will need to narrow this down to far more bite sized specific parts

Comment: It is a single page application where forms should be enabled one by one. Once previous one is filled. I have edited the question.

Comment: @charlietfi any solutions.

Comment: Simplest is only present applicable form to user. They can't submit what they can't see or fill out. Still far from enough detail about your SPA to provide reasonable solutions. Strongly suggest you take the time to read through [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated pictures.